# Reference not valid error in excel hyperlink

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I am using the below piece of code to add hyperlink to a given cell(`"A1"` here):

```
Workbook workbook = _excelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\temp\\test1.xlsx",
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing);


Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];
Range rangeToHoldHyperlink = worksheet.get_Range("A1", Type.Missing);
string hyperlinkTargetAddress = "www.bing.com";

Range excelRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
object[,] valueArray = (object[,])excelRange.get_Value(
                XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);


 worksheet.Hyperlinks.Add(
                rangeToHoldHyperlink,
                hyperlinkTargetAddress,
                string.Empty,
                string.Empty,
                valueArray[1, 1].ToString());
```

It adds the hyperlink. But, on clicking it, it says:
 `Reference not valid`
On hovering the mouse over cell text, it displays the hyperlink as:
`excel_file_path\hyperlinkTargetAddress`

Why it is doing so?
How this can be overcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add different types of hyperlinks. By default, Excel assumes that you want to link a file in your hard drive (in the folder where the spreadsheet it). To tell Excel that you want a website, you have to write the full address (with the starting `http://` bit).

```
string hyperlinkTargetAddress = "http://www.bing.com";
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Its working now. One question: What if I want to give some path(different path where excel file is lying) of my machine as hyperlink? Giving "C:\test\t" is not working.

Comment: @Aashish for an external file you have to use  `string hyperlinkTargetAddress = @"file:///C:\test\t";` What it assumes by default are other Excel ranges/workbooks. If you have any other doubt, just open and Excel spreadsheet, go to Insert -> Hyperlink, select the option you want and see what it writes.